# R Zeroinfl model

Tags: r, glm, zero

I am carrying out a zero-inflated negative binomial GLM on some insect count data in R. My problem is how to get R to read my species data as one stacked column so as to preserve the zero inflation. If I subtotal and import it into R as a single row titled Abundance, I loose the zeros and the model doesn't work. Already, I have tried to:

1. stack the data myself (there are 80 columns * 47 rows) so with 3760 rows after stacking manually you can imagine how slow R gets when using the **pscl** `zeroinfl()` command (It takes 20mins on my computer!, It still worked)
2. The next problem concerns a spatial correlation. Certain samplers sampled from the same medium so as to violate independence. Can I just put medium in as a factor in the model?

Comment: Can you show a snippet of the data that we can work with? For 2. You can, but if you have many media they'll be using many degrees of freedom and any predictions would be for those set of media only. Inclusion of a random effect would be preferable with many media, but **pscl** doesn't allow random effects. There are other R options for however.

Comment: Several questions. (1) Can you clarify your question in #1 (is it "how can I do this correctly but more efficiently"?) (2) with @DirkEddelbuettel: how many media? (3) Are you intrinsically interested in the zero-inflation or are you just trying to do correct statistics? If the latter then you may indeed be better off aggregating -- the aggregated data may no longer be zero-inflated.

Comment: I presume Ben meant s/Dirk/Gavin/ here.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I am trying to do correct statistics :-)

Comment: Sorry Ben, Yes "how can I do this correctly but more efficiently" is what I meant to say re: the ZINB model. I basically have 80 species and 16 samplers (times three changes= 48 samplers). I had 4 sites with 4 samplers in each (but each pair of samplers in each site were sampling the same media) so hereth lie the problem. Excellent re: aggregating the data, as my data is overdispersed then a negative binomial glm will suffice then yes?

Comment: So, to summarize, 16 samplers in 4 sites, each pair of samplers sampled the same media (so 2 media per site). This was done 3 times. Richness, Evenness etc. can this all be analysed using a GLM also? overdispersion isn't an issue with sp. richness.

Comment: @platypezid, maybe you should move the second question to crossvalidated.com? Elaboration on the first question (see Dirk's comment) would be needed, though.

Comment: @Ben Bolker, Hi Ben when you say that "the aggregated data may no longer be zero-inflated", do you have any reference for a paper or study where this has been done previously?

Comment: not specifically.  Have you read Zuur's book on mixed models?

Answer (score 0):

3760 rows take 20 mminutes with PSCL? my god, I have battle 30.000 rows :) that´s why my pscl calculation did not finish...

However, I then worked with a GLMM including nested random effects (lme/gamm) and a negative binomial distribution setting the theta to a low value so that the distribution handles the zero inflation. I think this depends on the degree of zeros. In my case it was 44% and the residuals looked rather good.