# Poisson Based Regression models code in R runs very slow

Tags: r, regression, poisson

I am working on a count data and, trying several different Poisson Fixed Effects Regression Models by using zeroinfl (from pscl package) and pglm (from pglm package) for not zero inflated models. However, my R code runs very slow and it takes more than 9-10 hours. For clarification, I am adding fixed effects manually by adding time and ID dummies.

```
model<- zeroinfl(y~ x1+ x2+ x3+ x4 + as.factor(time) 
               + as.factor(ID) | 1, data = df, dist = "poisson")
```

I am aware of that question: [R Zeroinfl model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682921/r-zeroinfl-model). However, my data is highly zero inflated with mean 0.587 and median equals to 0 and I am afraid this feature of the data can be lost by suggested methods. I am kind of new to R. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding additional covariates to the zero-inflation part of the model -- it seems like you would at least want time & ID fixed effects on the zero-inflated portion as well as the count portion of the model. In addition, with two fixed effects, it's easy to be near boundaries if you have a small number of observations for even some combinations of ID & time.

Comment: @mikebader thank you, it makes great sense. Could you please also give a little bit more detailed statistical explanation of why I should add the same additional covariates to the zero-inflation part of the model? Appreciate it.

Comment: Three different issues arise here:
1. Your current model is pretty close to a non-inflated Poisson model; if zeros exist they are likely not random;
2. Building on (1) above, if you are trying to estimate the effects of x1-x4 *within* ID and *within* time (which is what FEs do), then you want to include FEs to account for differences in both the zero and count portions of the model;
3. A separate problem arises if you have few observations for different combinations of ID and time because the answer would then be on the boundary

Comment: How many observations do you have, and how many levels of `ID` ? You might be creating a gigantic model matrix and giving yourself a memory problem ...

Comment: @BenBolker Another great point. I have more than 87,000 observations and around 2500 ID's. Is there a way to get around creating a gigantic model matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given what you've said so far, it may be worth trying

```r
library(glmmTMB)
model <- glmmTMB(y~ x1+ x2+ x3+ x4 + as.factor(time) 
               + as.factor(ID),
          dispformula = ~ 1, 
          data = df, 
          family = "poisson",
          sparseX = c(cond = TRUE))
```

You can do whatever you like with the zero-inflation component (e.g. `dispformula = ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4` to include those covariates). If you want the zero-inflated model matrix to be sparse as well, add `zi = TRUE` to the `sparseX` vector.

The reason (particularly for the `sparseX`) is that generating the model matrix for a data set with 87K rows and 2500 IDs with `zeroinfl` will (I think) create a model matrix that is approximately `2500*87e3*8/2^30 = 1.620501` gigabytes ...